# Is it normal to use the present perfect to confirm a statement in the simple past?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

Is it normal to use the present perfect to confirm a statement in the simple past ?

> Q : I visited Paris last year.
>     A : Oh, you have visited Paris ?
>
> Q : She travelled through Eastern Europe.
>    A : Oh, she has travelled through Eastern Europe ?

Answer (score 1):

It's all right to respond that way, since it's not a mistake, because your response is grammatically correct. However, as a learner, you might want to pay attention to the nuances there.

"I visited Paris." - This simply puts the emphasis on the verb, *visited*, may be for the first time, or it might serve as an answer to the question: "What did you last summer?"
"I have visited Paris." - The use of *present perfect* here means that I have gone to Paris in the past, and may be, more than once. It's a direct answer to "Have you visited Paris?"

That said, it isn't normal to respond to a question the way you've written. Usually, people responding spontaneously, say as follows:

"I visited Paris last year."
 - Oh, did you?

"I have visited Paris." - Oh, have you?

The same can be applied to your other example.